# How do I keep object location from being increased exponentially after each call to draw function?

Tags: html, canvas, draw, setinterval

Simple animation that creates a firework-like effect on the canvas with each click. The issue is the animation is made with a setInterval(draw) and every time the canvas is redrawn the location of each particle is += particle.speed. But with each click the particles move faster and faster as it seems the speed of each particle is not reset.

As you can see with a couple clicks on the [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/k74Hj/1/): , with the first click the particles move very (correctly) slowly, but with each subsequent click the speed is increased.

JS used is pasted below as well, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


    canvas.addEventListener("click", startdraw, false);


    //Lets resize the canvas to occupy the full page
    var W = window.innerWidth;
    var H = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = W;
    canvas.height = H;


    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

    //global variables
    var radius;
    radius = 10;
    balls_amt = 20;
    balls = [];

    var locX = Math.round(Math.random()*W);
    var locY = Math.round(Math.random()*H);


    //ball constructor
    function ball(positionx,positiony,speedX,speedY)
    {   
        this.r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
        this.g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
        this.b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
        this.a = Math.random();
        this.location = {
            x: positionx,
            y:positiony
        }
        this.speed = {
            x: -2+Math.random()*4, 
            y: -2+Math.random()*4
        };

    }




    function draw(){

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        //Lets reduce the opacity of the BG paint to give the final touch
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

        //Lets blend the particle with the BG
        //ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

        for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
        {
            var p = balls[i];
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(p.location.x, p.location.y, radius, Math.PI*2, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+p.r+","+p.g+","+p.b+", "+p.a+")";

            ctx.fill(); 
            var consolelogX = p.location.x;
            var consolelogY = p.location.y;
            p.location.x += p.speed.x;  
            p.location.y += p.speed.y;


        }
    }
    function startdraw(e){

        var posX = e.pageX;     //find the x position of the mouse
        var posY = e.pageY;     //find the y position of the mouse
        for(i=0;i<balls_amt;i++){
            balls.push(new ball(posX,posY));
        }

        setInterval(draw,20);
        //ball[1].speed.x;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each click `startdraw` is called, which starts every time a new periodical call (`setInterval`) for the `draw` method. So after the 2nd click you have 2 parallel intervals, after the 3rd you have 3 parallel intervals. 
It is not exponentially, only linearly increasing :)

A possible dirty fix: 
Introduce an `interval` global variable, and replace this row:

```
         setInterval(draw,20);
```

with this one:

```
        if (!interval) interval = setInterval(draw,20);
```

Or a nicer solution is to start the interval at the onLoad event.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval will repeat its call every 20th ms, and returns an ID.
You can stop the repetition by calling clearInterval(ID).

```
var id = setInterval("alert('yo!');", 500);
clearInterval(id);
```